# Org mode LaTeX preview environments

Tags: org-mode, latex, preview-latex

Is it possible to preview in org mode also environments

> \begin{theorem}
>
> hello world
>
> \end{theorem}

I tried but I can't get the ***Theorem 1.2.3*** header.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `theorem` environment by default in LaTeX: you have to define one. Unless you are using a package that defines that environment, you have to use the `\newtheorem` command to create a `theorem` environment. So try:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

* Theorem

\begin{theorem}
    hello world
\end{theorem}
```

Then preview with `C-c C-x C-l` should work.

See Lamport's book (2nd ed.), p. 56-57.